# Recursively add items to 2-tuple of lists in SML

Tags: recursion, sml, smlnj

I want to recursively take a list of 2-tuples (ex [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]) and turn it into a tuple of two int lists (result: ([1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]) ). I understand how to do the opposite (take the tuple of two lists and turn it into a list of tuples) but I do not understand how to do the recursive call on the same list.

This is my code so far, I think I am close:

```
fun toTuple [] = ([], [])
| toTuple [((x:int, y:int)::xs)] = (x::[], y::[]) toTuple (xs).
```

The compiler gives me the error:

```
Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch]
  operator: int list * int list
  in expression:
(x :: nil,y :: nil) unzip
```

I believe that means I need to put an operator between (x::[], y::[]) and toTuple (xs). I want the recursion to put the tuple items into the same list I have created, and I do not know the operator for doing something like that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with explicit accumulator parameters:

```
fun loop (xs, ys, nil) = (rev xs, rev ys)
  | loop (xs, ys, (x, y) :: zs) = loop (x :: xs, y :: ys, zs)

fun toTuple xs = loop (nil, nil, xs)
```

---

In hindsight, the following would have been more efficient:

```
fun loop (xs, ys, nil) = (xs, ys)
  | loop (xs, ys, (x, y) :: zs) = loop (x :: xs, y :: ys, zs)

fun toTuple xs = loop (nil, nil, rev xs)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! As I am trying to learn more about the language in general, may I ask why a second function is used? Is it to make it simpler and pass in the two empty values that will eventually be the first and second parts of the return tuple?  Also, is there absolutely any way to do this without using a secondary function? Your solution will work, but I would like to understand more about this problem.

Comment: @Scaldiron: The main reason why I use a helper function is to make the state management explicit. I just happen to find recursive code less easy to understand when an unbounded amount of program state is implicit. Other than this, I have nothing to add to what Simon Shine already said.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do that using a plain recursive function:

```
fun toTuple [] = ([], [])
  | toTuple ((x,y)::pairs) =
      case toTuple pairs of
        (xs, ys) => (x::xs, y::ys)
```

It processes the remaining `pairs` recursively, unpacks the result as `(xs, ys)`, and adds `x` and `y` to that result afterwards. Instead of a case-of, you might use a let-binding:

```
fun toTuple [] = ([], [])
  | toTuple ((x,y)::pairs) =
    let val (xs, ys) = toTuple pairs
    in (x::xs, y::ys)
    end
```

And if you didn't perform this kind of pattern matching directly in the function `toTuple`, you might have to move the unpacking and re-packing of the result into a separate function:

```
fun add (x,y) (xs,ys) = (x::xs, y::ys)
fun toTuple [] = ([], [])
  | toTuple (pair::pairs) = add pair (toTuple pairs)
```

Those three approaches are more or less equivalent.

In response to @pyon's tail-recursive variant,

> ```
> fun loop (xs, ys, nil) = (rev xs, rev ys)
>   | loop (xs, ys, (x, y) :: zs) = loop (x :: xs, y :: ys, zs)
>
> fun toTuple xs = loop (nil, nil, xs)
> ```
>
> As I am trying to learn more about the language in general, may I ask why a second function is used? Is it to make it simpler and pass in the two empty values that will eventually be the first and second parts of the return tuple? Also, is there absolutely any way to do this without using a secondary function? Your solution will work, but I would like to understand more about this problem.

If you compare my three solutions to pyon's, his solution is different in some ways: He has a helper function `loop` that is recursive, whereas the version I wrote with the helper function `add`, `add` isn't recursive and only manages unpacking and re-packing the tuple. `toTuple` still has just one argument, but `loop` has two more, one for storing the temporary results `x :: xs` and one for the `y :: ys`.

When you process a list from left to right, but accumulate the result in an argument, the first element in the input becomes the first to get added to the accumulated result, which means it ends up as the last element of the result. (You can think of the list as a stack here.)

This is not so fortunate when the accumulated result was a list of elements that are supposed to be in the same order as the input. You can best see this by evaluating the functions by hand:

First, for my case-of version of `toTuple [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]`:

```
toTuple [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
  ~> case toTuple [(3,4),(5,6)] of
       (xs, ys1) => (1::xs1, 2::ys)
  ~> case (case toTuple [(5,6)] of
             (xs', ys') => (3::xs', 4::ys')) of
       (xs, ys) => (1::xs, 2::ys)
  ~> case (case (case toTuple [] of
                   (xs'', ys'') => (5::xs'', 6::ys'')) of
             (xs', ys') => (3::xs', 4::ys')) of
       (xs, ys) => (1::xs, 2::ys)
  ~> case (case (case ([], []) of
                   (xs'', ys'') => (5::xs'', 6::ys'')) of
             (xs', ys') => (3::xs', 4::ys')) of
       (xs, ys) => (1::xs, 2::ys)
  ~> case (case (5::[], 6::[]) of
             (xs', ys') => (3::xs', 4::ys')) of
       (xs, ys) => (1::xs, 2::ys)
  ~> case (3::5::[], 4::6::[]) of
       (xs, ys) => (1::xs, 2::ys)
  ~> (1::3::5::[], 2::4::6::[]
  ~> ([1,3,5], [2,4,6])
```

Second, for @pyon's version:

```
toTuple [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
  ~> loop ([], [], [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)])
  ~> loop (1::[], 2::[], [(3,4),(5,6)])
  ~> loop (3::1::[], 4::2::[], [(5,6)])
  ~> loop (5::3::1::[], 6::4::2::[], [])
  ~> (rev [5,3,1], rev [6,4,2])
  ~> ...
  ~> ([1,3,5], [2,4,6])
```

**Edit:** As @pyon points out in a comment, these use the same amount of memory and time. The difference lies in my version using an implicit (call) stack, and his version using an explicit (argument) stack.

Comment: The only advantage I find in my solution is that my state management is completely explicit, hence it requires less mental energy (to me, at least) to figure out how it works.

Comment: My solution uses no less space than yours (I don't use the so-called “call stack”, but I use two auxiliary lists for exactly the same purpose), and your solution requires no less time than mine (you still have to reverse the lists, when you essentially transfer them from the “call stack” to the final answer).